# Is it true that if a function is bound by a constant so is it's derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have an intuition that I haven't been able to prove nor disprove:

Given a parametric function $p$ if $||p(t)|| < C$ then $||p'(t)|| < C$. The intuition behind that claim is that the change in the magnitude of a function cannot be higher than the magnitude of that function.

I am not sure if this is true. Is it?

Comment: If the function is $p$ analogous to your position in space, then $p'(t)$ is your velocity.  Knowing $||p(t)|| < C$ tells you that you are trapped on the interval from $-C$ to $C$, but just because you are contained in a given region doesn't limit how fast you can move around within that region. Just like knowing that you are on a 1-mi racetrack doesn't mean you can only go $1$ mph.

Comment: "the change in the magnitude of a function cannot be higher than the magnitude" Well, the absolute collective quantity of change over the entire time can't be.  But that is not at all and and not intuitively what the derivative is.  Intuitively the derivative is the *rate* of change over small intervals that can be arbitrarily high and near infinite.  Now intuitively the *average* rate of change seems to be bounded but that doesn't mean there can't be "bursts of speed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very false. Look at $f(x) = \sin(e^x)$. Here, the function is bounded, but the derivative isn't.

Note that the derivative measures "how fast" the function is changing. But just because the function doesn't change very much, it doesn't impose any constraints on the rate of change. This is precisely what the example above illustrates: $\sin(\cdot)$ is a nice bounded function, so $\sin(e^x)$ is also bounded. However, the derivative is $e^x \cos(e^x)$. And because of the exponential multiplying the cosine, the derivative changes vary rapidly (and is actually oscillating). Try to sketch these two graphs side by side and compare them.

---

The "converse" to what you're saying is true. If the derivative is bounded; i.e there is a $C>0$ such that for all $x$, $|f'(x)| \leq C$, then this imposes a limit to how much the function can change: for all $\xi,\eta$, we have $|f(\xi) - f(\eta)| \leq C |\xi - \eta|$. This can be proven easily using the mean-value theorem.

Comment: But, just to clear, it certainly doesn't imply a bound on the function. E.g., any linear function. Of course, on a bounded interval it does.